# Using multiple if-then statements

Tags: bash

To make my question more precise, here is my script.  Getting unexpected end of file error.  Can somebody point out what I'm missing.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
#
DZHOST='XX.XX.XX.XXX'
DZUSER='ftpuser'
DZSPASS='Ftppass'
DSHOST='XX.XX.XXX.XXX'
DSUSER='userftp'
DSPASS='passftp'
#

DNASN='/home/dsmn/ASN'
{
if [ "$(ls -A $DNASN)" ];
    then
    ftp -n -u $DZSHOST <<-ASN_END
     quote USER $DZUSER
     quote PASS $DZPASS
     prompt
     cd /home/DS/PROD/Import/ASN
     lcd ASN
     bin
     mput *.*
     bye
    ASN_END
    cp $DNASN/*.* ./backup/
fi
}

DNGRA='/home/ds/GRA'
#{
#if [ "$(ls -A $DNGRA)" ];
#        then
#        ftp -n -u $DSHOST <<-GRA_END
#         quote USER $DSUSER
#         quote PASS $DSPASS
#         prompt 
#         cd GRA
#         lcd GRA
#         bin
#         mput *.*
#         bye
#        GRA_END
#        cp $DNGRA/*.* ./backup/
#fi
#}
DNGRB='/home/ds/GRB'
{
if [ "$(ls -A $DNGRB)" ];
    then
    ftp -n -u $DZHOST <<-GRB_END
     quote USER $DZUSER
     quote PASS $DZSPASS
     prompt
     cd /home/DS/PROD/Import/GRB
     lcd GRB
     bin
     mput *.*
     bye
    GRB_END
    cp $DNGRB/*.* ./backup/
fi
}
```

Some parts are remarked since the ftp access is not yet finalized.  had to change the directory names,etc because of confidentiality so I apologize if there are inconsistencies. 
I get this error that points to the end of the script.
syntax error: unexpected end of file

Many thanks from a newbie.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: I get this error. ./transferfile.sh: line 71: syntax error: unexpected end of file.  Each condition runs perfectly on its own.  Hope you can help me.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to show us a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `If [folder1 not empty];` it should be `if` (lower case); is it a typo when copying or is this how it is in your code?

Comment: sorry typo error only. Each part actually checks a directory in different locations for a file or files then transfers them via FTP to different sites.  Each condition works on its own.  When I combine at least 2, then the error shows up.

Comment: can anybody point out what causes the unexpected end of file error in the script above?

Comment: Finally got it.  After a lot of reading from the forums, decided to add brackets {}.  I enclosed the ftp part after then in {} and everything worked.  Thanks everyone for the patience.  Two thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can include as many if statements in your script as you like. You can even have nested if's.

Yet maybe a `case` statement will make your code much cleaner...

you could try looping through your folders and using case to decide what to do with each one of them.

Comment: since the script is now working using if-then statements, I'll try to enhance it by using loops just like what you suggested.  Thanks.